# Creating decoratos in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any simpler one for creating decoratos than writing whole custom tool that looks for attributes and then creates new c# class?

For example I have a data source that returns me some data in XML format.
Then I have my intenral C# model of this data. At the end I need to convert the data to some other format.

This is very straightforward code. Parse this field from xml to the type x and then assign it to variable y.

Then again there is very straighforward code: get subset of fields and then convert them to JSON.

Instead of wrtiting the whole code I'd like to write something like that:

```
[MyModelDecorator]
abstract class ModelX {
    [FromXML="number"]
    [JSON]
    abstract int i();
    [FromXML="title"]
    [JSON]
    abstract string s();
}
```

After saving this I'd like to get a new class `ModelXImpl` that extents `ModelX` and has a method to create from XML, to convert to JSON and that have getters and setters for each abstract property.

Comment: Have a look at [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I checked, but using T4 I'd need to write this class in T4, not c#

Comment: You don't write the class in T4. In T4 you write code that transforms some input and creates an output. Usually you write the logic in an include file. Then for each class you want to create, you write one small T4 template including the logic and defining the name of an input file. The input file can be any type of file, *.cs, .xml, .json, .txt

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes I know. But look i.e. at AutoValue for https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14u_h-lMn7f1rXE1nDiLX0azS3IkgjGl5uxp5jGJ75RE/edit#slide=id.g2a5e9c4a8_0114 - you can write your code in java and you get it extended.
I'd like to write a class in c# and get it extended, not generate class.

Comment: Then maybe, you are looking for [AOP](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/aop) (Fody, PostSharp, ...).

Comment: You used `Straighforward` a couple times but your question is still not straight forward. May be if you could write those straight forward psuedo of class structures what class design you currently have and what you want to generate on the fly would help understanding your problem. And `AOP` is not supported out of box in C#(you would need libraries) and yes T4 may be a way to go.